# How to create dataframes from a list of string and then concatenate into single dataframe without using dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

`list1 = ['brand1','brand2']`

I want to create a dataframe such that:

`import pandas as pd
for i in list1:
       "df_" + i = pd.read_csv('filepath'+i)`

i want to create dataframe as:

`df_brand1= (containing dataframe of brand1)`

`df_brand2= (containing dataframe of brand2)`

Comment: Looks like you need `global`

Comment: Either hard-code it if it is fixed - or if it is variable then this is what `dict`s are for `data["df_"+i] = pd.read_csv(...)`.

Comment: Even though `dict` can be useful in this case, there is also a way to do what OP asked. `locals()["test"] = "xxx`. This will create a variable named 'test' with the value 'xxx'. I was writing answer half way when the question became closed.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun Yes, while you can do that, it is nearly always a bad idea to do so.

Comment: @AChampion May I ask why it is a bad idea so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: @AChampion if i use dictionary then what to do when I have to concatenate these two dataframe into new dataframe, when i tried doing  it, i got following error.. ``` first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame ```

Comment: As per documentation: "Note
 
The contents of this dictionary should not be modified;
...". If you are not in a function locals() will return globals() which does technically work but also a bad idea.

Comment: @AayushTomar, just use a `list` or you can do `dict.values()` and if you need individual args then use `*` expansion syntax.